# RubyGem version error: rack(1.0.0 not ~> 1.0.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rack

I was working on a rails project on my laptop and pushing code to github.  Now I cloned the project on my desktop.

when running:

```
rake db:migrate
```

I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
RubyGem version error: rack(1.0.0 not ~> 1.0.1)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Before this error I had to run the following commands:

```
sudo gem install -v=2.3.5 rails
sudo gem update rack
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo gem install -v 1.0.1 rack
```

Comment: sudo gem install -v 1.0.0 rack

Comment: That sucks! I mean, the fact that I needed this and have no idea who or what has this strange dependency. Great answer, +1